# Disable JBoss 5 logging to the console

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I still have to deal with JBoss 5 where I want to disable the logging to the console.
I found in jboss-log4j.xml the appender "CONSOLE".

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="FATAL"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

If I delete the appender JBoss throw an error but I found these solutions:

1.Delete one line:

`param name="Target" value="System.out"`

2.Set logging level:

`param name="Threshold" value="FATAL"`

But I am not so happy with theses solutions, because I do not know if there are any side effects (solution 1. is in my eyes critical) Is there a "better" solution?

Greetings

**Update**

It is possible to remove the appender

`<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
 ...
 </appender>`

I only forgot to update the root category. here is a reference to the CONSOLE appender which should be also removed
Delete this:

`<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>`

After I removed it no error occur and also no logging to the console.