# Turn off console logging jboss 5

Tags: log4j, webserver, jboss5.x

I have read that one of the Best practices for performance tuning in JBoss is to tun off consloe logging, how can i achieve that?
I'm using Jboss 5.
Thank you

Comment: This question is pretty much a duplicate of this [Disable jboss 5 logging to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077015/disable-jboss-5-logging-to-the-console) but unfortunately the person did not answer their own question so I cannot mark it as a duplicate - but his *update* at the bottom should get you going!